# Discrepancy between web interface and API

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api

Using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4, I'm issuing a simple query to get Geo/Location data by city.

In the web interface, I see:

```
City                           Sessions
Saint Cloud
Jun 15, 2016 - Jun 30, 2016    60,279
```

In the API response, I see:

```
"dimensions": [
  "Saint Cloud"
],
"metrics": [
  {
    "values": [
      "60300"
    ]
  }
```

These numbers do not match.

Here's the JSON request body in Fiddler:

```
{
    "reportRequests": [{
        "dateRanges": [{
            "endDate": "2016-06-30",
            "startDate": "2016-06-15"
        }, {
            "endDate": "2015-06-30",
            "startDate": "2015-06-15"
        }],
        "dimensions": [{
            "name": "ga:city"
        }],
        "metrics": [{
            "expression": "ga:sessions"
        }],
        "orderBys": [{
            "fieldName": "ga:sessions",
            "orderType": "VALUE",
            "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"
        }],
        "pageSize": 10,
        "samplingLevel": "LARGE",
        "viewId": "123"
    }]
}
```

I've tried various sampling levels and I get the same results.

The web report does **not** have the yellow "this report is based on" sampling box. I'm not adding any segments.

Is there a way to get the API results to match the web interface exactly? The reason is I need to have a domain expert validate the reports, and this person will be using the web interface as the source of truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the API is aggregating the data based on city name, and city names are not unique. In this case there is a Saint Cloud, MN and a Saint Cloud, FL. The web interface does **not** aggregate these two; you can see this by adding an Include filter for the city name.

[image]

Note that 60279 + 21 = 60300, the result returned by the API.

The workaround is to add a secondary dimension of `ga:cityId` to the query:

```
"dimensions": [{
    "name": "ga:city"
}, {
    "name": "ga:cityId"
}]
```

This gives the correct results:

```
"dimensions": [
  "Saint Cloud",
  "1020086"
],
"metrics": [
  {
    "values": [
      "60279"
    ]
  }
```

I'd call this a bug.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug.  City Names are not unique in the world.  The web interface most likely uses city id.

Comment: @DaImTo Sure, but aggregating by city name is almost certainly not what users intend. I'd like to see the Pit of Success, where the obvious path leads to correct results.